# CoreData in one single separate thread

Tags: xcode, multithreading, cocoa, core-data, thread-safety

What I want in short is:

- Core Data that runs without blocking the main thread
- entities with relationships
- bindings in InterfaceBuilder

I have tried 'everything', but it turned out that there are too many difficulties with Core Data on two or more threads and two NSManagedObjectContexts and bindings and entities with relationships and so on. These threads can make CoreData very complicated.

Nevertheless I want to use Core Data and I want it to run in the background for good UI response.

So I wonder, is it possible to completely run everything related to Core Data in one separate thread, which is not the main thread?

I will send everyone 50 bucks, if I finally find a solution that works...

Comment: I can suggest to see [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/)

Comment: Not entirely sure, but anything UI-related (and hence bindings in Interface Builder) should be in the main thread, iirc. So be prepared to do at least some inter-thread communication.

Comment: @Monolo: I knew, I would here that. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used two NSManagedObjectContext instances to push some longer lasting data tasks onto another thread with Grand Central Dispatch.

As long as you be careful to merge this context with the one on the main thread used to fetch data then you should be able to get some performance that way.

Comment: After two hours of reading, this seems to be the only option. What I'll do now is to create a small test app from ground up. I'll make a new question for upcoming difficulties...

Comment: Here's my first question:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346455/how-to-set-a-relationship-to-a-from-one-nsmanageobject-to-another-in-a-different  :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can help you, but perhaps you can create a new NSOperationQueue and add whatever core data functions you need to in the background. So in your class have a property that is NSOperationQueue, then in the -viewDidLoad methods, you create new one:
myOperationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new]; Whenever you want to do an operation you can add it to the queue and I believe that it will execute on a separate thread (self.myOperationQueue addOperation: someFunction) and if you want to interact with the main thread, then call assert([NSThread isMainThread]) in the beginning of your method call. I am using Core Data and threading in a different way, but from the second thread I am able to create a temp object that the NSManagedObject is created from.